# Deployment source code with sql connectivity on Azure Virtual machine

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

Any one can suggest me to upload publish source code (C#) with database connectivity on MS-Azure virtaul machine. I am facing issues after deployment done, to run the application.